# Winforms / SQL Server, Why are 2 zeros being added to my textbox?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I have a textbox used to store a decimal amount of money in the form £0.00, this textbox is then connected to an SQL Server database where the datatype for the connected column is set to decimal(2,2).

The issue is occurring however when I try to save the data in the form using the Save button on the binding navigator. Two additional '0's are added to the data in this row only and I am not sure what is causing it.

For example upon saving, '£0.03' is changed to '£0.0300' etc.

The code for save button press event is:

```
this.TableBindingSource.EndEdit();
this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.DataSet);
```

I have tried setting the datatype to nvarchar(5) to no avail, the textboxes maxlength property is also set to 5 characters so I am confused as to how this is being exceeded.

Comment: Typo, I meant (2,2), I've changed it above

Comment: A decimal value does *not* store a currency symbol. Either your database column is *not* decimal, or a different format is applied when reading it. The decimal values *are* the same. How do you *read* the values? How do you assign them to the text box?

Comment: I'm not saying it was SQL Server specifically, but there appears to have been an error in communication between the SQL Server Table and the windows form. I have changed the datatype to nvarchar and the dataSet data type to system.string and max length 5, which seems to have done the trick.

Comment: Not a very good idea to store number as a string. Why not use `smallmoney` type? Your problem is probably in TextBox formatting, not in the value saved to the table.

Comment: I don't know what the error was specifically but I assume it was to do with the data type used in the DataSet. This does not have an option for smallmoney, which is why I chose string. I am not performing any calculations or manipulation to the amount if thats what you're worried about, its purely storage/retrieval.

Comment: Check https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/c860168f-46e5-4786-a68d-ac69c6a7a248/formatting-a-textbox-for-currency?forum=winforms&prof=required

Comment: `In the properties for the textbox, expand the databindings property and select the Advanced property then click the ... elipse button. In the resulting dialog, you can enter the format.`